# Complexity of two nested loops with the inner loops stepping dependend on the outer loops variable

Tags: language-agnostic, big-o, time-complexity, pseudocode

```
function(n) {
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        for(int j=1; j<=n; j+=i)
            printf("*");
}
```

I thought this was O(n²logn), but the book says O(n*log(n)), so where am I going wrong?

Comment: It can't be O(n^2) because the inner loop is incremented by the outer loop variable, e.g. j goes 2, 4, 7, 11, etc

Comment: @SebastianPiu: it can't be *bigger than* O(n^2); just because `i` is involved somehow doesn't automatically make it less than O(n^2).

Comment: yaa that ws my mistake, but i think it has to be n^2 logn...am i correct??

Comment: every time i increases, you have half the iterations of the inner loop if I´m not missing anything?

Comment: Each increase in i does *not* halve the iterations, although it does reduce them.

Comment: no not half but it goes with the rate of n/i with every loop...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for each value of i, inner loop executes `(n-1)/i+1` times because `for each i the inner loop executes according to following equation which satisfies an AP ie.. 1+(x-1)*i=n which implies x = (n-1)/i + 1`

obviously it is going to form an AP. So now all you have to do is sum the expression for 1<=i<=n.
 that is

```
((n-1)/1 +1) + ((n-1)/2+1)+ ((n-1)/3+1) //upto n because max value of i can be n
that becomes n + Summation((n-1)/i) where i can go upto n.
```

Evaluation that you get O(nlogn) as complexity

Comment: but for the inner loop which is descending at the rate of n/i with every iteration , we will do summation over them from i=1 to n which evaluates to nlogn and the outer loop which goes for n times so the product will be n^2 log n.... this is what i understood, correct me if m wrong!!!1

Comment: No no! you are doing a little mistake. You are already summing it n times depending on value of i.... so you do not need to multiply the complexity nlogn again by n.... because you have summed the expression for each value of i already